# Onclicking on radio button show calender and as well as one input box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

all I am trying to show the calendar and input box when the user clicked on the radio button.
I have made one modal popup by using below code and 
when I click on the send button it will open a modal popup with two radio buttons and when I click on the close popup with a reminder 
button it will show calendar as well as input box.

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="radio" name="reminder">Close popup with reminder </br>
                    <input type="radio" name="reminder">Close popup without reminder
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me out how can I do that.

Here is the image reference

[image]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the bootstrap grid inside the modal then add change events to the radio button; if the radio button has a true value, it would show the .note div which contains the reminder, else hide it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input class="radio-reminder" type="radio" name="reminder" value="true" /> Close popup with reminder
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-6 date" style="display:none;">
                <input class="form-control" type="date" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row note" style="display:none;">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <br>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Reminder" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row no-reminder">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <br/>
                <input class="radio-reminder" type="radio" name="reminder" value="false" /> Close popup without reminder
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".radio-reminder").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "true") {
          $(".note").show();
          $(".date").show();

          $(".newSelect").remove();
        } else {
          $(".note").hide();
          $(".date").hide();

          var newSelect = $("<div class='col-xs-6 newSelect'><br><select class='form-control'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></div>")
          $(newSelect).appendTo($(".no-reminder"));
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @suresh Updated the code to follow that behavior. Added the class .date on the column of input type date, then hide them together with .note

Comment: what if i want to add select box onclick on second  radio button ?

Comment: i have added some code to show default date and time as tomorrow date with 8am always but my code returns only tomorrow date not time can you please check and correct me

Comment: <script>
    // Declare variables
    var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    // Set values
    $("#inputDate").val(getFormattedDate(tomorrow));
    // Get date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD
    function getFormattedDate (date) {
        return date.getFullYear()
            + "-"
            + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
            + "-"
            + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    }
</script>

Comment: Hi suresh will you post this another question, and comment the link to the new question here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813392/display-default-tomorrow-date-and-time-as-8am-in-date-field

Comment: i have posted can you please check once

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have to include the input elements in the HTML. Then you can use jQuery to hide/show those elements based on the value of the clicked radio button.

Please note that how I have added value attribute to the radio buttons.

```js
$('input[name=reminder]').click(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "1")
    $('#inputDate, #inputText').css({'display': 'block'});
  else
    $('#inputDate, #inputText').css({'display': 'none'});
});
```

```css
input[type=date]{
  float: right;
}
#inputDate, #inputText{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="radio" name="reminder" value="1">Close popup with reminder <input type="date" id="inputDate"/>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="inputText"/>
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="reminder" value="2">Close popup without reminder
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have idea about zend

Answer (score 1):

use below code snippet

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
   if($(this).val() == 'calendar'){
       $('#date-input').show();
       $('#calendar').show();
       $('#selectGroup').hide();
       
   }else{
       $('#date-input').hide();
       $('#calendar').hide();
       $('#selectGroup').show();
   }
});
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
    
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send</button>
    
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
    
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="radio" name="reminder" value="calendar"> Close popup with reminder 
                            
                            <input type="date" id="calendar" style="display: none;" />
                            <br/>
                                            <input type="text" value="" id="date-input" style="display: none;" />
                                            <br/>
    
                            <input type="radio" name="reminder"> Close popup without reminder 
    <br/>
    
            <div class="form-group" id="selectGroup" style="display: none;">
               <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
               </select>
            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: if i want to add select box on click on second radio button?