# Display default tomorrow date and time as 8Am in date field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all i am trying to display tomorrow date and time(8am) in my date field. as i have tried some code
    it is showing only tomorrow date but not time can any one help me how to show time 8am as by default

Here is my code:

```
     <div class="col-xs-6 date" style="display:none;">
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="inputDate"/>
                        </div>

    <script>
    // Declare variables
    var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    // Set values
    $("#inputDate").val(getFormattedDate(tomorrow));
    // Get date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD
    function getFormattedDate (date) {
        return date.getFullYear()
            + "-"
            + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
            + "-"
            + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone help me how can i display time as by default 8 am and later if user want to change they can change their date and time according to their requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a `Date` field. This is not the same as datetime ;)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change your input type to [datetime-local](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_datetime-local.asp). So that it will support for date & time.
Then use the [moment](http://momentjs.com/) to format date.

```js
$("#inputDate").val(moment().add(1, 'days').hours(8).startOf('hour').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6 date" style="display:block;">
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" id="inputDate" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: it is showing date and time but what if  user want to change their own time and date

Comment: if user want to change their date and time insead of default one how they can chang? we have to show date and time calender rite?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_datetime-local.asp check the browser support here. it will automatically show calendar for modern browser. else you can use jquery ui datetpicker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: But be careful not every browser supports `datetime-local`

Answer (score 2):

You can use moment.JS for formatting and operation on the date.

http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js

```
var tomorrow = moment(new Date())
              .add(1,'days')
              .hours(8)
              .minutes(30)
              .format('DD/MMM/YYYY HH:mm');

console.log(tomorrow)
```

Comment: Please change the input type datetime-local from date 

<div class="col-xs-6 date" > <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" id="inputDate"/>   </div>

//script 
var tomorrow = moment(new Date())
              .add(1,'days')
              .hours(8)
              .minutes(30)
              .format('DD/MMM/YYYY HH:mm');

$("#inputDate").val(tomorrow);

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = new Date; 
a.setDate(a.getDate()+1); 
a.setHours(8); 
a.setMinutes(0); 
a.setSeconds(0); 
console.log(a);
```